# How to store text with multi line separators into database?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-4.0, sql-server-2000

I have some text,

e.g

```
line one \r\n
line two \r\n
line threee.
```

In my database, I have a column define as type `text`, then I use Entity Framework to map that column, the code generate by Entity Framework is type `string`

I can successfully save that text into the column in the database. However, from Management Studio, I couldn't see those line separators, when I do copy value, and paste to notepad, they have become one line of text.

Anyone know what the problem is?

Thanks.

Comment: copy value from Management Studio to notepad and use query to read data from the column are two different things. You can try paste it to Word.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should stick to NVarchar when it comes to store text data (one of the reason is that it supports more characters).
Heres an extract from msdn:

*"ntext, text, and image data types will be removed in a future version of Microsoft SQL Server. Avoid using these data types in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use them. Use nvarchar(max), varchar(max), and varbinary(max) instead"*.

More info:

- ntext, text, and image deprecated :http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx
- replace text: http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/05/26/sql-server-2005-replace-text-with-varcharmax-stop-using-text-ntext-image-data-types/

Comment: -1 Partly correct, but not relevant to the question. Using HTML encoding or URL encoding when storing in the database is not a good idea at all. The `HttpUtility` class doesn't even have any methods called `Encode` and `Decode`.

Comment: That's better, but it's still irrelevant.

Comment: Microsoft itself suggest to abandon the Text type and adopt NVarchar for several reasons. Considering the question is about the Text type this answer even if it doesn't scope the new line issue it is still relevant imho. I think it's a good tip to advise someone that what is he using it will be deprecated in favour of a better solution.

Comment: This is what's called a copy-paste-answer, where you paste some information about some aspect of the question, but the answer doesn't do anything at all towards answering the actual question. I'm sure that you didn't intend it as such, but this is spam.

Comment: I agree it doesn't answer the question and of course I did get those info from somewhere(the source is linked). I put the lights on some aspects (issues in this case) that haven't been considered. I'm not looking to argue over an answer, but I believe spam its when you post something that is completely out of argument.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is simply that Management Studio doesn't support all characters. It removes the line breaks when you copy the value.

If you change the result from grid to text (Query -> Results To -> Results to text, or <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>), and select the value, you will see that the text comes out as separate lines.

Answer (score 0):

This could quite simply be a problem with the management studio. Try querying the database from C# and printing the field's value. You will see immediately if the CRLFs are there.